# How can I add HTML to a Stacklayout inside a Scrollview in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application I have a Contentpage with a Scrollview in it. The Scrollview in turn contains a StackLayout with lots of labels with text. In the middle of this I want to insert some static HTML.

I have tried adding a Webview with static HTML as a child to the StackLayout but the Webview is not visible then (Probably the height gets calculated to zero)

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is there some other way to add HTML in the between all the labels?

```
StackLayout mainLayout = new StackLayout ();

// Adding many labels of different sizes
mainLayout.Children.Add (new Label {Text = "Label text"});

mainLayout.Children.Add ( new WebView {
            Source = new HtmlWebViewSource {
                Html = "<html><body>Hello</body></html>"
            }
});

// Adding many more labels of different sizes
mainLayout.Children.Add (new Label {Text = "Even more Label text"});

Content = new ScrollView {
            Content = mainLayout
        };
```

Comment: check https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/

Comment: I've had a similar problem, and my solution required to write a custom renderer, in order to hook up on OnPageFinished of the WebViewClient, then use javascript to compute the height, and so to set it appropriately. If you have more or less always the same content, though, you could simply set the HeightRequest yourself to an appropriate value, it'll be much simpler ;)

Comment: Sadly the content can vary a lot in size, so it is similar to your case, is there some code you would consider sharing, I am no expert at custom renderers yet :)

Answer (score 3):

See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/, in particular:

> WebView requires that HeightRequest and WidthRequest are specified
>   when contained in StackLayout or RelativeLayout. If you fail to
>   specify those properties, the WebView will not render.

The HeightRequest and WidthRequest are not set in the code snippet above, so fixing this should be the next thing to try.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the issue of the content not showing, but I still have an issue since I do not know the size of the html since it is input from a user in an exernal system, is there any way to calculate that?

Comment: Try setting HeightRequest to some reasonable guess, and VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand. If that doesn't give you a result you're happy with, you might need a custom renderer as suggested by markusian.

Answer (score 3):

I found a great solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/167131#Comment_167131)

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class HtmlLabel : Label
    {
    }
}
```

iOS renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
            var nsError = new NSError();
            attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

            var text = e.NewElement.Text;

            //I wrap the text here with the default font and size
            text = "<style>body{font-family: '" + this.Control.Font.Name + "'; font-size:" + this.Control.Font.PointSize + "px;}</style>" + text;

            var myHtmlData = NSData.FromString(text, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);
            this.Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, attr, ref nsError);

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (this.Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
                var nsError = new NSError();
                attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

                var myHtmlData = NSData.FromString(this.Control.Text, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);
                this.Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, attr, ref nsError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HtmlLabel), typeof(HtmlLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    class HtmlLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control?.SetText(Html.FromHtml(Element.Text), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                Control?.SetText(Html.FromHtml(Element.Text), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found `Html.FromHtml`is pretty basic. I ended up binding [this library](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) which helped with lists and (with a bit of work) span tags.

Comment: Thanks! Works great in my scenario.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make a UWP renderer ?