# Button on top of the Scrollview does not show up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms

I have something like this so far for my view:

```
   public StackLayout OffersSlideViewCarouselChild(Offer offer)
{
    Image productImage = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(offer.Image.Replace("https://", "http://"))),
        HeightRequest = 270, 
        WidthRequest = 270,
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit
    };

    var topStackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        Spacing = 0

    };
    topStackLayout.Children.Add(productImage);

    StackLayout contentStackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
    var savedBtn = SavedButtonLayout(offer.IsSelected, offer.Id);
    var redeemBtn = RedeemBtnLayout(offer.Id);
    var timeRemainingLabel = TimeRemainingLayout(offer, offer.Id);


    contentStackLayout.Children.Add(new UILabel(16) {
        Text = offer.ProductName,
        TextColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_OFFERCELL_PRODUCT_TEXT),
        FontFamily = CoreTheme.FONT_FAMILY_DEFAULT_BOLD,
        WidthRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
});

    contentStackLayout.Children.Add(new UILabel(14)
    {
        Text = offer.Headline,
        TextColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_OFFERCELL_PRODUCT_TEXT),
        FontFamily = CoreTheme.FONT_FAMILY_DEFAULT_BOLD,
        WidthRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
    });

    contentStackLayout.Children.Add(new UILabel(14) {
        Text = offer.LongRewardsMessage,
        TextColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_DEAL_PAGE_LONG_REWARD_MESSAGE_RED),
        FontFamily = CoreTheme.FONT_FAMILY_DEFAULT_BOLD,
        WidthRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
    });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(offer.PowerMessage)) {
        var htmlText = string.Format("<html><body style='color:#9b9b9b'>{0}</body></html>", offer.PowerMessage.Replace(@"\", string.Empty));

        var browser = new WebView() {
            //HeightRequest = (DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultheight > 600) ? 500 : 400,
            HeightRequest = 800,
            Source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { Html = htmlText },
        };
        browser.Navigating += OnNavigating;

        contentStackLayout.Children.Add(browser);
    }

    var nestedStackLayout = new StackLayout()
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
    };

    nestedStackLayout.Children.Add(topStackLayout);
    nestedStackLayout.Children.Add(timeRemainingLabel);
    nestedStackLayout.Children.Add(contentStackLayout);

    var mainScrollView = new ScrollView()
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
        Content = nestedStackLayout
    };

    var mainStackLayout = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 5,
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        Children = { savedBtn, mainScrollView, redeemBtn }

    };

    return mainStackLayout;
}

private StackLayout SavedButtonLayout(bool isSelected, int offerid)
{
    int buttonsToShow = 2;
    bool displaySaveButton = true;

    if (IsPremisesOffer (offerid)) {
        buttonsToShow = 3;
        displaySaveButton = false;

    }

    btnShare = new UIFieldDefinition(_pageFieldDefinition.ShareButtonDefinition); 
    btnShare.Text = "SHARE";
    btnShare.ClassId = offerid.ToString();
    btnShare.WidthRequest = (DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth / buttonsToShow) - 40;
    btnShare.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(167, 188, 33);
    btnShare.VerticalContentAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    btnShare.HandleClick(btnShare_Clicked);


    btnSave = new UIFieldDefinition(_pageFieldDefinition.SaveButtonDefinition);
    btnSave.Text = isSelected ? "UNSAVE" : "SAVE";
    btnSave.ClassId = offerid.ToString();
    btnSave.WidthRequest = (DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth / buttonsToShow) - 40;
    btnSave.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(167, 188, 33);
    btnSave.VerticalContentAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
    btnSave.HandleClick(btnSave_Clicked);

    rl = new StackLayout {
        Spacing = 10,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(196, 221, 57),
        Padding = new Thickness(40, 5, 5, 5),
        WidthRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth
    };

    rl.Children.Add(btnShare);
    if (displaySaveButton) rl.Children.Add(btnSave);

    return rl;
}

public UIFieldDefinition RedeemBtnLayout(int offerid)
{
    int buttonsToShow = 1;

    btnRedeem = new UIFieldDefinition(_pageFieldDefinition.RedeemButtonDefinition);
    btnRedeem.Text = "REDEEM NOW";
    btnRedeem.ClassId = offerid.ToString();
    btnRedeem.WidthRequest = (DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth / buttonsToShow) - 10;
//  btnRedeem.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
//  btnRedeem.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
    btnRedeem.HandleClick(btnRedeem_Clicked);



    return btnRedeem;
}
```

However, I am noticing that the Redeem button does not even display on the view (It's supposed to be fixed on the bottom).

The scrollview works but the buttom is missing. Why?

Please let me know if you need further code details.

Comment: Have you tried with different screen resolutions or devices? with a bigger device does it cut's off, if yes then you better check you width height request properties also the padding and spacings are important!

Comment: @MarioGalván, yes it gets cut off. Which properties precisely (name wise) and should I check for stack layouts or specific elements instead?

Comment: All of the elements, Layouts and views, also check the VerticalOptions it may interfere  to use FillAndExpand, Xamarin suggest to leave Vertical and Horizontal Options as it is (default).

Comment: @MarioGalván, that did not resolve anything. I removed all VerticalOptions and Horizontal Options. Nothing was different.

Comment: What about changing the paddings, spacings and width and height request?

Comment: I have tried that as well. It would be more useful to point specifically to an element that might be the offender rather than blinding guessing trial and error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you using a RelativeLayout instead of a StackLayout? With the exception of the horizontal positioning of the first element, it looks like a vertical StackLayout should do it.  Also, what are you trying to accomplish with WidthRequest and HeightRequest on the ScrollView?

Comment: Why not use a RelativeLayout? Is that what's messing up my Layout? I was trying to set the ScrollView to wrap_content or fit the content. Not sure if it made sense what I did. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that RelativeLayout is causing the problem, but it sometimes pays to simplify. I would try getting rid of the HeightRequest on the ScrollView, and replacing it with VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand. I would also change the RelativeLayout to be a StackLayout. The interactions between nested layouts can be subtle sometimes. I also don't see where this is tied to a Page of some kind - this is potentially important as scrollable layouts can't be nested, so if OffersSlideViewCarouselChild is nested within a scrollable view, that could also be a problem.

Comment: @DavidS, there is also a grid with a slider to slide the view horizontally. Here's the snippet: http://pastebin.com/a5BrQbdg. That's on top of this view. Could that be it?

Comment: @DavidS, I fixed the webview content to a bigger heightrequest. I realize that was the issue. The only thing now is the button is missing from the buttom of the screen? Is it being pushed out?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the redeem button. If you still have a HeightRequest on the ScrollView, that could push the button off the screen. One way to test that is to try moving the redeemBtn before mainScrollView in the Children list of mainStackLayout. If you see the button displayed properly (except in the wrong place), then the problem is likely with the ScrollView taking up too much space. If you don't the button, then the problem is with the button definition itself. I include this possibility because you don't have the code for the button above.

Comment: Great idea and if I do see the button, how do the adjust the scroll view height to fit is content and show the button? I'm having the issue with webview...how can I make it fit its dynamic content?

Comment: Have you changed the HeightRequest of the ScrollView from the code snippet you originally posted?  For the WebView, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065393/how-can-i-add-html-to-a-stacklayout-inside-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @DavidS, exactly the issue I might be having. I am setting the webview to a fixed height but would that be pushing out the button? Why would it push it out if the button is outside the scrollview? Just want to understand the hierarchy. Thanks!

Comment: Moved to a new answer as the comment section is getting too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108654/discussion-between-kala-j-and-davids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving here from comments above. There are two separate issues from what I can tell, and as far as I can tell, are unrelated:

1. The WebView, nested inside the ScrollView, is not big enough to fully display the content.
2. The button that is supposed to be at the bottom of the screen is not displaying.

For both of them, the answer is probably in how you are setting HeightRequest. There have been a lot of suggestions by myself and other commenters to change or get rid of some of the HeightRequest settings, and I'm not sure of the current state of your source code. So assuming those are still there:

1. For solving the WebView issue, read [How can I add HTML to a Stacklayout inside a Scrollview in Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065393/how-can-i-add-html-to-a-stacklayout-inside-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms).  This will let you figure out the right HeightRequest to use. The short answer is that depending on exactly what you want to happen, you may need a custom renderer. Note that the HeightRequest for the WebView will not affect any layout outside of the ScrollView.
2. For solving the issue of the button not appearing, get rid of the HeightRequest setting on the ScrollView, and the VerticalOptions on the StackLayout created in SavedButtonLayout.

I am assuming you did the experiment suggested above to make sure that the redeemBtn will render if placed before the ScrollView, and it does show up then. If not, you first need to fix that.

Comment: Two things 1) I got rid of the HeightRequest on the ScrollView 2) I got rid of the VeritcalOptions on the SavedButtonLayout. DO I need to get rid of anything on the mainStackLayout that the ScrollView is nested inside? Do I need to get rid of the VerticalOptions on the mainScrollView? Thanks! I don't have the issue with contents not showing up in webview anymore since I added a longer heightrequest. However, the only issue now is the button not showing up (but it does show up if I put it as part of the SavedButtonLayout).

Comment: Updated my code in my post. Take a look when you have time. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have "fixed" this by changing the HeightRequest then your real problem is the fixed pixel size of all your views and layouts, I recommend you DON'T use fixed pixel sizes for different screen resolution this will be a bigger problem later, What you can do is get the Screen size and do the math to fit all your elements of the view, one way to get the width and height of the screen is on the `OnSizeChanged` event of `Pages` (Like ContentPage), something like this:

```
SizeChanged += SizeChanged;
void SizeChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Layout.WidthRequest = Width * 0.3;
    Layout.HeightRequest = Height * 0.35;
}
```

Comment: can I use this for a resizing a button if text changes?

Comment: By text you mean a Label or a Text inside a Entry?

Comment: I mean like a button. Resize the button if the text inside the text changes length.

Comment: Well there is a `Label` object which you can set the `Text` property and there is a `Entry` object which you can also set the `Text` property (This is only for context) the `Entry` object has a listener called TextChanged which you can use to change resize account for example:
`
Entry t = new Entry ();
t.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
void OnTextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e){//Do stuff}`

Comment: If it is a Label maybe the best thing to do is bind the Text property to a bindable string property in your view model and when this text changes then you can change resize the button but you have to bind the HeightProperty of the button to your view model also.

Comment: Well, I mean the bindable text property for Button. Is that the same approach as the label you mentioned above? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can bind the Text property of the button and if it changes then you can change the Width of height request of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109850/discussion-between-mario-galvan-and-kala-j).

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is pretty busy. A few things:

1. Set `VerticalOptions` to `EndAndExpand` for `redeemBtn`.
2. Set `VerticalOptions` to `StartAndExpand` for `savedBtn`.
3. Set `VerticalOptions` to `Fill` for `mainScrollView`.
4. Set `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand` for `mainRelLayout`.
5. Set `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions` to `Fill` for
   `mainStackLayout`.

I think that will get you to where you want to be.

The options that include "Expand" will grow the element to accommodate the desired height of its contents.

Comment: VerticalOptions for redeemBtn and savedBtn... for the button itself or for the StackLayout?

Comment: In any event, still not fully scrollable with the changes you suggested... Thanks for your help!